# TypeLoadException after upgrading from EF Core 3 to 6

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-6.0

After upgrading version of Web API to core Framework from 3.1 to 6.0 the below mentioned error occurs after compiling the Web API

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'get_Info' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.'

The nugget `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` used in Classlibrary application with .Net standard version 2.0 and the class library is used in Web API application

There is dependency of core and standard frameworks

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file once.

Comment: `in Classlibrary application with .Net standard version 2.0` EF Core 6 doesn't support .NET Standard 2.0 at all. It seems you haven't upgraded all projects in the solution. If you want that library to use EF Core, it *must* be upgraded to .NET 6.

Comment: .NET Standard 2.0 is only needed if you want to share code with .NET Framework 4.x, which doesn't support EF Core 6 anyway. If you want to create a cross-platform class library in .NET Core, target .NET 6 directly. You may want to check [When to target net5.0 or net6.0 vs. netstandard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0#when-to-target-net50-or-net60-vs-netstandard) in the docs